# Pop framework animation - combination of kPOPLayerPositionX and kPOPLayerPositionY

Tags: ios, animation

Upon clicking on a wrong answer, I am shaking the cell in X direction (similar to the wrong password animation on macbook).

```
POPSpringAnimation *sprintAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
sprintAnimation.springBounciness = 20;
sprintAnimation.velocity = @400;
sprintAnimation.repeatCount = 3;
[self pop_addAnimation:sprintAnimation forKey:@"springAnimation"];
```

However, I want an animation like [image]
 tilting keeping the center of the object constant. Which property can help me with this?